# String concatenation python

Tags: python, string, quote

I have a file extension, I got it in this way:

```
fileName, fileExtension = os.path.splitext(abspath)
```

now I need my file extension to became a pattern, something like '*.fileExtension', included the quote characters. I should use it in a `fnmatch` like this:

```
if fnmatch.fnmatch(name, pattern)
```

any idea?

Comment: I very much doubt you want to include the quote characters when using this as a pattern for `fnmatch`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use string concatenation:

```
pattern = '*' + fileExtension
```

or use string formatting:

```
pattern = '*{}'.format(fileExtension)
```

or

```
pattern = '*%s' % fileExtension
```